# Inside vue resource callback, cannot access any jquery method?

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js, vue-resource

See the fiddle linked below, I have commented the line where I am getting the error

```
this.get().then(function(result){
    this.orders = this.orders.concat(result.data);
    // I m getting concat is not a function error inside vue resource promise
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mithicher17/7q6Lj8Lp/25/

Comment: Hum, I'm pretty sure "this" inside the `function(result)` is the function

Comment: After reading your fiddle, did you consider `getAll` could result in `this.orders` not being an array anymore?

Comment: Could you try to spread into with spread operator - `_this.orders = [...d]` ? 
Also make sure that is this.orders array by @RC. suggestion

Comment: Just a heads up that he appears to be using Vue 1.

Comment: Thanks for replying.... @rc could not get your point

Comment: My point was: in `var d = JSON.parse(response.data); _this.orders = d;` if `d` is some error string or something else (`undefined`?) then you can no longer use `concat` on `this.orders` because it's no longer an array.